# spark-submit is not exiting until I hit ctrl+C

Tags: apache-spark, hortonworks-data-platform

I am running this spark command to run spark Scala program successfully using Hortonworks vm. But once the job is completed it is not exiting from spark-submit command until I hit ctrl+C. Why?

```
spark-submit --class SimpleApp --master yarn-client --num-executors 3 --driver-memory 512m --executor-memory12m --executor-cores 1 target/scala-2.10/application_2.10-1.0.jar /user/root/decks/largedeck.txt
```

Here is the code, I am running.

```
/* SimpleApp.scala */
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

object SimpleApp {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val logFile = "YOUR_SPARK_HOME/README.md" // Should be some file on your system
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf) 
    val cards = sc.textFile(args(0)).flatMap(_.split(" "))
    val cardCount = cards.count()
    println(cardCount)
  }
}
```

Comment: You should include relevant portions of your source code.

Comment: I have added code as well.

Comment: I added exit in my program and it is working as expected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to call stop() on context to exit your program cleanly.

Comment: Which one is more appropriate stop() or exit? exit is also working for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same kind of problem when writing files to S3. I use the spark 2.0 version, even after adding stop() if it didn't work for you. Try the below settings

In Spark 2.0 you can use,

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").appName("App_name").getOrCreate()
spark.conf.set("spark.hadoop.mapred.output.committer.class","com.appsflyer.spark.DirectOutputCommitter")
spark.conf.set("mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.marksuccessfuljobs", "false")
```

Comment: Did these settings worked for you or you are only suggesting?